# How to import a list of git projects into eclipse and custom build them all together?

Tags: eclipse, git

The product that I am working on contains multiple git projects. I work mostly on only one of them and they are all built together. How can I import all the projects and build them together with a custom build script?

Comment: Are those java projects?

Comment: You don't need to import the projects you're not working on into Eclipse to run your custom build script, because all files and folders exist in the cloned repository folder (so-called _Working Tree_). The _Git Staging_ view will also track changes of files of not into Eclipse imported projects.

Comment: No. they are mostly Go and C++ projects. The project tree has multiple git projects. I work on only one of them in C++. But, the project has multiple dependencies for building, that exists in a different build folder and make needs to be run on the project root to create a full build. How can I orchestrate this on eclipse?